# Is it possible to output a static file in bin when building with Cabal or Stack?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I want to output static html files alongside my build output (giving access to these files to my Haskell program).

Here is my current project structure:

```
MyProject/FrontEnd -- contains static html, js and css files.
MyProject/Backend -- contains the stack Haskell project
```

I want that when I run `stack build` inside the Backend directory, it both builds my Haskell project and then copies the Frontend directory and puts it in the build output, alongside my executable.

I'm not super familiar with Cabal or Stack, but I've looked mostly inside the cabal documentation and saw that there was the `data-dir` parameter, that looks like it does what I want, but even when adding:
`data-dir: ..\Frontend` in my cabal file, I get this warning:
`data-dir: ..\Frontend' is a relative path outside of the source tree. This will not work when generating a tarball with 'sdist'.` and the files are not present in the output.

I haven't seen a similar flag in Stack.

Is it possible to do what I want? Or I am going to have to create my own script to do this for me (call stack build, and then output the files manually)?

Comment: Moving your cabal file to `MyProject` (and adjusting all references as appropriate) would bring `MyProject/Frontend` into the source tree, thus avoiding the problem noted in that error message. (I have successfully used `data-dir` and `data-files` in that way for a project of mine.)

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing this, but looks like it's going to be my best option, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`file-embed`](https://www.stackage.org/package/file-embed) package to use Template Haskell to embed the contents of files or directories directly into your executable. `wai-app-static` uses this, for example, to create a self contained static file server if requested.